# Java - How to retrieve all chrome tabs details?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome

I wish to use a class that provides the option to get all open tabs.
Unfortunately, I can only find code in js and other.. and I don't really know how to use it in my Java code..

Comment: What do you mean *to get all open tabs* ?

Comment: For example: You open the chrome browser and enter google.com & youtube.com in 2 different tabs, I wish to make a list:

Comment: The only way seems to implement a Chrome extension and use "native messaging". See https://github.com/vakho10/Native-Messaging for an example project.

Comment: It is also possible using Selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43787744/873282

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to find browser physical details with Java other than the request headers. You Cannot.

On the other hand you can send the info you found with Javascript to server(Java) through a request.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty solution:

From Java, you can send keyboard event (see `Robot` class). So you could emulate *Ctrl+1* to switch to the first tab (*Ctrl+2* to second tab and so on), then *Ctrl+L* to highlight the URL and *Ctrl+C* to copy it in the clipboard. Then acess the clipboard content from java :

```
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
    String url= (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
```