# How to open a link in new tab (chrome) using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-tab

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\softwares\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://mail.google.com/");
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("www.facebook.com")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

New tab is opening but URL link is not opening.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I checked with below code and it works fine for me. I found answer from [here](http://www.testingexcellence.com/open-new-tab-browser-using-selenium-webdriver-java/).

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
            
    String baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");

    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //switches to new tab
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0)); // switch back to main screen        
    driver.get("https://www.news.google.com");
```

Comment: It is working fine but one more browser window is opening up

Comment: It works for me in new tab. Can you confirm whether this (`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"t");
`) command opens new window or new tab to you?

Comment: didn't worked for me. only one tab is opening with the 1st url

Comment: Throwed Exception at line  driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
 at test.SeleniumTest.main(SeleniumTest.java:31)

Comment: I tried above in chromedriver but it didn't work. Then I tried ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()"); and this opened a new tab.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on a Mac. I tried with `command` instead of `control` with `T` but it still failed. Very interested in a solution.

Answer (score 49):

this below code works for me in Selenium 3 and chrome version 58.

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://yahoo.com");  
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: This is the best solution as Ctrl + t is always broken on chrome browser, https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5462

Comment: Super it works as expected ctrl+t is broken in chome but one issue in chromium "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer" can be handled with catch block thanks for the answer

Comment: driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size()-1));  <---- driver not seeing new opened tab without this, working with previous one. More universal variant to get last one.

Answer (score 15):

I have tried other techniques, but none of them worked, also no error produced, but when I have used the code below, it worked for me.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open()");
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and nur's answer above? Nur responded more than a year before you.

Answer (score 11):

Selenium 4 is already included this feature now, you can directly open new Tab or new Window with any URL.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("www.Url1.com");     
//  below code will open Tab for you as well as switch the control to new Tab
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);

// below code will navigate you to your desirable Url 
driver.get("www.Url2.com");
```

download Maven dependencies, this is what I downloaded -

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

you can refer: https://codoid.com/selenium-4-0-command-to-open-new-window-tab/

watch video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SpCMkUKq-Y&t=8s

google out for - WebDriverManager selenium 4

Answer (score 6):

If you can get the link element you can use this. It will also take you to the tab that you have opened.

```
WebElement link= driver.findElement(By.tagname("a"));  
String keyString =   Keys.CONTROL+Keys.SHIFT.toString()+Keys.ENTER.toString());
link.sendKeys(keyString);
```

Comment: This will open new window instead of tab.

Answer (score 3):

First open empty new Tab by using the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> and then use [`.get()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn@7074/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#get(java.lang.String)) to fetch the URL you want. Your code should look something like this -

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);

driver.get("www.facebook.com");
```

If you want to open a link on the current view in a new tab then the code you've written above can be used. Instead of `By.linkText()` make sure you use the appropriate [`By`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn@7074/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) selector class to select the web element.

Answer (score 3):

I had used the below code to open a new tab in the browser using C# selenium..

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

js.ExecuteScript("window.open();");
```

Comment: for Java it is
`JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript("window.open()");`

Answer (score 2):

Selenium can only automate on the  WebElements of the browser. Opening a new tab is an operation performed on the webBrowser which is a stand alone application. For doing this you can make use of the Robot class from the java.util.* package which can perform operations using the keyboard regardless of what type of application it is. 
So here's the code for your operation.
*Note that you cannot automate stand alone applications using the Robot class but you can perform keyboard or mouse operations*

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","softwares\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.keyPress(keyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rob.keyPress(keyEvent.VK_T);
rob.keyRelease(keyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rob.keyRelease(keyEvent.VK_T);
```

After this step you will need a window iterator to switch to the new tab:

```
Set <String> ids = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator <String> it = ids.iterator();
String currentWindow = it.next();
String newWindow = it.next();
driver.switchTo().window(newWindow);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("www.facebook.com")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

Answer (score 2):

for clicking on the link which expected to be opened from the new tab use this

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
driver.get("https://www.yourSite.com"); 
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("path_to_link")); 

Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL) 
       .click(link) 
       .keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL) 
       .build() 
       .perform(); 

ArrayList<String> tab = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles()); 
driver.switchTo().window(tab.get(1));
```

Comment: This looks more like it, but does `link` above needs to be `element` (or visa versa)?

Comment: Ah, also it doesn't seem to work with org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

The original poster is asking on how to open a link on a new tab. So this is how I have done it in C#.

```
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://microsoft.com");
        IWebElement eventlink = driver.FindElement(By.Id("uhfLogo"));
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.KeyDown(Keys.Control).MoveToElement(eventlink).Click().Perform();
```

This actually performs a Control+Click on the selected element in order to open the link in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple browser or a window by using below code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://yahoo.com");  

WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
driver1.get("google.com");

WebDriver driver2 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver2.get("google.com/gmap");
```

Comment: I'm not completely clear why this has received so many down votes. All other answers I have come across have either not worked or would force me to go beyond the selenium built-in framework (javascript commands). I do see the issue with using this for many tabs and the potential for system resource abuse. However, I really just need two tabs and this allows me to stay within the selenium framework. Thanks Satheesh Kumar P for this different answer that does accomplish the required task.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do a robot to my little son and just play a Youtube video and than show a robot dancing.

For some reason, commands like CONTROL + T explained above was not working for me and maybe it is not the correct answer but I solved my problem using custom Javascript script like this:

```
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
            {
                var link1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GIgk4yuHOQ";
                //open a music
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(link1);
                var link2 = "https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/fbe53d6d-c13f-4eec-9bcf-62f19cfab15a/d4m0h4v-9442b1f2-6a49-4818-8f51-5ebe216f043c.gif?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwic3ViIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsImF1ZCI6WyJ1cm46c2VydmljZTpmaWxlLmRvd25sb2FkIl0sIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiIvZi9mYmU1M2Q2ZC1jMTNmLTRlZWMtOWJjZi02MmYxOWNmYWIxNWEvZDRtMGg0di05NDQyYjFmMi02YTQ5LTQ4MTgtOGY1MS01ZWJlMjE2ZjA0M2MuZ2lmIn1dXX0.BTTlingNpBqH5O9dNVienFsArNqkfUc7KXnIgHumrBQ";
                //Dance robot, dance
                driver.ExecuteScript($"window.open('{link2}', '_blank');");
                Thread.Sleep(20000);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to open a link in new tab in using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871).

---

### Usecase A: Opening an adjacent blank tab and iterating through an iterator

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.Set;

  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class NewTab_blank_iterator {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
          driver.get("https://mail.google.com/");
          String firstWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
          System.out.println("First Window Handle is: "+firstWindowHandle);
          // Opening an adjacent blank tab
          ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('','_blank');");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
          Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
          // Using iterator
          Iterator<String> itr = allWindowHandles.iterator();
          while(itr.hasNext()) {
              String nextWindow = itr.next();
              if(!firstWindowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(nextWindow)) {
                  driver.switchTo().window(nextWindow);
                  System.out.println("New Tab Window Handle is: "+nextWindow);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  First Window Handle is: CDwindow-0D89767363ED691767000F01E6712D0B
  New Tab Window Handle is: CDwindow-7232D2058514ED22344F129D30A0CCE7
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: blank_tab]

---

### Usecase B: Opening an adjacent tab with an url and and iterating through an iterator

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.Iterator;
  import java.util.Set;

  import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class NewTab_url_forLoop {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options); 
          String url1 = "https://mail.google.com/";
          String url2 = "https://www.facebook.com/";
          driver.get(url1);
          String firstWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
          System.out.println("First Window Handle is: "+firstWindowHandle);
          // Opening Facebook in the adjacent TAB
          ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('" + url2 +"');");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
          Set<String> allWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
          // Using iterator
          Iterator<String> itr = allWindowHandles.iterator();
          while(itr.hasNext()) {
              String nextWindow = itr.next();
              if(!firstWindowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(nextWindow)) {
                  driver.switchTo().window(nextWindow);
                  System.out.println("New Tab Window Handle is: "+nextWindow);
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  First Window Handle is: CDwindow-01F5622275A2EA2C1ABE2F0CDEB3D09B
  New Tab Window Handle is: CDwindow-9E3349B91FB2FA4D5B7D4A90D0E87BD3
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: url_tab]

Answer (score 0):

To switch between tabs action class does not always works on all browser and on all webdriver. the best way is to use robot class. try this code.

```
        String website = "https://www.google.com";
        String website1 = "https://www.msn.com/en-in/";
        String controlpath = "C:\\Libraries\\msedgedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", controlpath);
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); //  Maximize browser
        driver.get(website);
        System.out.println("Google page");
        
        Robot robot = new Robot();                          
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); 
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
        
        //Switch focus to new tab
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        //System.out.println("Handle info"+ driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
    
        //Launch URL in the new tab
        driver.get(website1);
        System.out.println("msn page");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
        Thread.sleep(5000);
```