# How to open new tab in Chrome with Selenium-chromeDriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there anybody who used `ChromeDriver` to open new tabs in Chrome?

With this code I can open my `index.html` in Chrome:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get("localhost:3000")
```

And then I want to open `localhost:3000/cloudPeer.html` in a new tab:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
driver.get("localhost:3000/cloudPeer.html")
```

This works well in Firefox, *but in Chrome, it can't open a new tab, it just refresh the first page, and open the new page, the first page is now lost.*

I want to open these two pages at the same time and do some communication tests between them.

Comment: I know how it works in Java. Can you implement the same login in python and see that works? Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829329/how-to-open-a-link-in-new-tab-chrome-using-selenium-webdriver/34831289#34831289. Also is it t (in single quote) in python? In java, it is t in (double quote) to open a tab.

Comment: Please do not open multiple tabs.  Use multiple webdriver instances and open another window.  It is *much* more stable.

Answer (score 29):

This works for chrome-

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.google.com');")
```

Comment: How to switch tabs?

Comment: Use `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])` to switch to the most recently opened tab.

Comment: How to get the `page_source` ?