# Selenium webdriver switchin tab

Tags: selenium, tabs, webdriver, switch-statement

I am unable to open google in new tab please review this code :

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException
 {

 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Users//vbisht//Downloads//chromedriver.exe");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
 driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
 Robot r = new Robot();
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
 //Thread.sleep(10000);
 //driver.navigate().refresh();*/
 ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
 driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //switches to new tab
 driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
```

Comment: Format your code properly when you put a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a link in new tab (chrome) using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829329/how-to-open-a-link-in-new-tab-chrome-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

```
String parentWindowHandler=driver.getWindowHandle();// Store your parent window
String subWindowHandler = null;
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
  subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
}
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

The code below will open the link in new Tab.

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

The code below will open empty new Tab.

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("urlLink")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Robot Class, You can simply open it with Javascript Executor

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException, AWTException { System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Users//vbisht//Downloads//chromedriver.exe"); 
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //switches to new tab
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To open two different *urls* in two different *TABs*, once you initiate opening a new tab/window you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and then collect the *window handles*  and finally iterate through the *window handles* and then `switchTo().window(newly_opened)` as per the following example:

- Sample Code:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe.exe");
  WebDriver driver =  new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
  String first_tab = driver.getWindowHandle();
  System.out.println("Working on Google");
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://facebook.com/');");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(2));
  Set<String> s1 = driver.getWindowHandles();
  Iterator<String> i1 = s1.iterator();
  while(i1.hasNext())
  {
      String next_tab = i1.next();
      if (!first_tab.equalsIgnoreCase(next_tab))
      {
      driver.switchTo().window(next_tab);

      System.out.println("Working on Facebook");
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Working on Google
  Working on Facebook
  ```