# How to open new Tab using Selenium and also combine the link from 2 parts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

so what I am trying to do is create a auto sign in to google meet. Before the code runs, it asks for the code of the lesson which I store it in a variable called "lesson_code" and I want to combine it with the string of the link + lesson code.

So after signing in to gmail it redirects to google meet , since I did quite struggled with the buttons and xml thought of simply opening a new tab which would save quite a lot of time and it is slightly easier to achieve.

```py
def open_chrome():
    # create a new Chrome session
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\driver\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.maximize_window()
    # navigate to the application home page
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/")
    #get the username textbox
    login_field = driver.find_element_by_name("identifier")
    login_field.clear()
    #enter username
    login_field.send_keys(username)
    login_field.send_keys(u'\ue007') #unicode for enter key
    time.sleep(4)
    #get the password textbox
    password_field = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
    password_field.clear()
    #enter password
    password_field.send_keys(password)
    password_field.send_keys(u'\ue007') #unicode for enter key
    time.sleep(10)
    #navigate to google.meet
    googlemeet =driver.get("meet.google.com/"+lesson_code)
    time.sleep(5)
```

It does work up to the point of gmail, but it stops working at

```py
googlemeet =driver.get("meet.google.com/"+lesson_code)
```

the lesson code is stored like this:

```py
lesson_code=input("Whats is your code : ")
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you shouldn't be omitting the protocol `https://`, that is what is causing the error. You don't really need to assign the `driver.get()` call either.

Opening in other tabs and changing focus seems to give problems to a lot of people. If you run `googlemeet = driver.get("https://meet.google.com/"+lesson_code)` it will likely open in a whole new window, so I usually use some JS injection to do this.

```
    # Create url
    googlemeet = "https://meet.google.com/" + lesson_code
    # Inject JS to open new tab
    driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0])", googlemeet)
    # Switch focus to new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

If you don't want to use injection for some reason, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829329/how-to-open-a-link-in-new-tab-chrome-using-selenium-webdriver/34831289)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `https` or `http` to in your url too

so do `googlemeet = driver.get("https://meet.google.com/"+lesson_code)`