# Selenium Open Link In new tab

Tags: python, selenium, automation, auto

I would like to open links in a new tab instead a new window

When i press the green button a window pops up and I need to login there, instead of that I would love for selenium to open the link in a new tab instead a new window. Some info:

1. the link is gengerated by javascript and i have no idea how to work with that
2. it sends a request and i cant find anything usefull from it
3. the window redirects multiple times before becoming stable

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829329/how-to-open-a-link-in-new-tab-chrome-using-selenium-webdriver answer your question

Comment: Above link should help, but I'll ask: Why do you need this in a new tab vs window?

Comment: @DMart Because i cant obtail the link before opening, this will eventually run on a headless vps.