# Selenium Chrome VBA

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Set Driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
 Driver.Get URL
```

with this code i open a new chrome session. I need to open a new tab in existing running chrome session.

Any clue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a link in new tab (chrome) using Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829329/how-to-open-a-link-in-new-tab-chrome-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: The linked duplicate is C#, but the VBA API is mostly the same for ChromeDriver.